# Not loading the information from API

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to load information from the tmdb api in to a movie information app in flutter, When I run the app response status code fail and it throw the exception.

I think the problem is with the url but I don't know how to solve it

```
 void _populateAllMovies() async {
    final movies = await fetchMovies();
    setState(() {
      _movies = movies;
    });
  }

  Future<List<Movies>> fetchMovies() async {
    final response = await http.get(
        Uri.https('api.themoviedb.org', '/movie/popular?api_key= my api key'));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var movieData = jsonDecode(response.body);
      Iterable list = movieData["results"];
      return list.map((movie) => Movies.fromJson(movie)).toList();
    } else {
      throw Exception("Fail to load movies ");
    }
  }
```

If you need more information let me know.

Comment: What is the exact error? And did you add your API key to the url?

Comment: What is the `response.statusCode` ?

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad did not say it just throws the exception and yes I use the API key

Comment: @EduardoYamauchi  check to see if the server return a 200 ok response,
     then parse the JSON.

Comment: Did you test your request using a software such as Postman or Insomnia to ensure your request process correclty ?

Comment: @GuillaumeRoux yes I use postman

Answer (score 1):

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:wnetworking/wnetworking.dart';

class TheMovieDb {
  static const _base = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3';
  static const _apiKey = '11111111111111111111111111111';

  static FutureOr<void> fetchPopularMovies() async {
    await HttpReqService.
      getJson<Map<String, dynamic>>('$_base/movie/popular?api_key=$_apiKey')
      .then((response) => print(response));
  }
}

void main(List<String> args) async {
  await TheMovieDb.fetchPopularMovies();
  print('\nJob done!');
}
```

Result:

```
{page: 1, results: [{adult: false, backdrop_path: /9yBVqNruk6Ykrwc32qrK2TIE5xw.jpg, genre_ids: [28, 14, 12, 878], id: 460465, original_language: en, original_title: Mortal Kombat, overview: Washed-up MMA fighter Cole Young, unaware of his heritage, and hunted by Emperor Shang Tsung's best warrior, Sub-Zero, seeks out and trains with Earth's greatest champions as he prepares to stand against the enemies of Outworld in a high stakes battle for the universe...
...the Wire, video: false, vote_average: 6.5, vote_count: 1048}], total_pages: 500, total_results: 10000}

Job done!
```

You can replace `HttpReqService.getJson` function with your typical `http.get` function, but use `Uri.parse` instead of `Uri.https`

Comment: thank you it works  been stock for almost a day